# Closing on HTML click pattern, across large project

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, stoppropagation

I figure other developers have run into this before. We have a large code base with many components following this pattern:

```js
$('#elm').on('click',function($e){
    $e.stopPropagation();
    //... do stuff (i.e. Open something);
});

$('html').on('click',function($e){
    //... do oposite of stuff (i.e. Close something);
}
```

Our issue is, all the `stopPropagation`'s across the site are stopping closing of other components.  What we really want is a mechanism to only block the click handler for this component but not for others.

I'm looking for a solution which is the easiest to implement right now to fix our bugs and for our Multi-developer team to follow in the future.

Comment: +1 because that is a great idea!

Comment: Would `$e.preventDefault();` (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) do what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately that only stops the default action the browser usually takes. What I need is to detect clicks on the HTML element not originally from this element. I've written a plugin: https://github.com/krismeister/jQuery.notMyEvent but I'm still interested what technique people recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, **it is not possible to stop propagation using live events** this allows you to do hack and take advantage of this because the `.live()` method binds a handler to the `$(document)`, and identifies which element triggered the event up at the top of the hierarchy using the `event.target` property.

The `stopPropagation` stops the propagation from bubbling up the DOM hierarchy, but since the handler is at the document level there is no upper place to propogate to.

On the other hand note that events handled by `.delegate()` will bubble up to the elements to which they are binded to; event handlers bound on any elements below it in the DOM tree **will already have been executed by the time the delegated event handler is called**. These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling `event.stopPropagation()`

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/knr3v/2/

**Therefore you can use the `live` and `delegate` method instead of click, bind, on method to do exactly what you are explaining.**

Comment: You've a great understanding of the event phases in this solution.  $.live was removed in jquery 1.9, but this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/VmHpA/  Thanks alot!